# How to modify and fetch from map in cython?

Tags: cython, libc++

I am trying to get myself familiar with the usage of Cython, especially the code inside "with nogil". Now suppose my goal is to fetch and insert elements into the map and vector (dict and list in python) without the global interpreter lock, and my tentative code is below:

```py
from libcpp.map cimport map
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libcpp.pair cimport pair

a = {'abc':[1], 'b':[2,3]}
cdef map[string, vector[int]] c = a
cdef int b = 0
cdef vector[int] d;
cdef pair[string, vector[int]] entry;
print(c['b'][1])

with nogil:
    d.push_back(1)
    d.push_back(5)
    entry.first = 'c'
    entry.second = d
    c.insert(entry)
print(c)
```

However, the line

```py
entry.first = 'c'
```

gives an error: Coercion from Python not allowed without the GIL.

I also tried to modify it to be:

```py
entry.first = b'c'
```

but it still doesn't solve the problem.

Can someone modify the above code chunk for me? It would be even more helpful if someone can point me to the documentation that at least has the functions for each Cython data structure? I am having a hard time finding it on google.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code has multiple problems, so it would also be possible to close as "needs more focus". Please try to create [mcve] next time (with minimal being the important part!). Right now `'b'` is interpreted as an unicode-object by Cython and thus you have issues with gil (using bytes, i.e. `b'b'` would solve it though).

Comment: How does the syntax of map in Cython differ from the syntax in C++?

Comment: please read the dupe: there is no difference for maps, the problem are the iterators, for which there is no operator `->` in Cython, also `*` is not interpreted as dereference-operator by Cython.

Comment: Hi @ead, I have updated my question. Could you take a look at your convenience? Using b in front of the string still doesn't solve the problem when I assign a string value to the first element of the pair.